# Why is my else condition in javascript is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have this javascript code that is not working. Althought the first conditional(if conditional) is working, the else conditional is not working. Sorry for my bad english.

```
function choice1()
    {
        if(pic_location<9)
        {
            if(document.getElementById("choice_1").value==character[numbers[pic_location]])
            {
                window.alert("Guess Correct!");
                score = score + 1;
                document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
                pic_location=pic_location + 1;
                document.getElementById("pic").setAttribute("src", "pictures/" + character[numbers[pic_location]] + ".jpg");
            }
            else
            {
                window.alert("Wrong Answer!");
                pic_location=pic_location + 1;
                document.getElementById("pic").setAttribute("src", "pictures/" + character[numbers[pic_location]] + ".jpg");
            }
            set_choices();
            document.getElementById("qn").innerHTML= pic_location + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if(pic_location==10)
            {
                document.getElementById("choice_1").value==character[numbers[pic_location]];
                window.alert("Guess Correct");
                score = score +1;
                window.location="game3.php";
            }
            else
            {
                window.alert("Wrong Guess!");
                window.location="game3.php";
            }
        }
        
    }
```

The if function is working fine when i run it but when I get to the last photo location which is 10, it always guesses wrong even though the answer is right.

Note: my function is the same for the four choices. They all have the same problems.

Comment: What is `character`?

Comment: Many of your variables, like `pic_location`, `score`, `character`, and others, look like mutable global variables, which is a bad-practice. Is there a reason you're not using function-parameters instead?

Comment: `window.location="game3.php";` <-- Setting `window.location` will trigger an immediate redirect and defeats the point of mutating variables beforehand (like `score = score + 1`, also consider using `score += 1` or `score++` instead to be more succinct.

Comment: Use linters like [ESLint](//eslint.org/play) or [JSHint](//jshint.com) to find problems with your code immediately. Relevant linter warning: _“Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.”_.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your suggestions. I applied these to my current code and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using comparison operator == instead of assignment =

```
 if(pic_location==10)
        {
            document.getElementById("choice_1").value==character[numbers[pic_location]];
            window.alert("Guess Correct");
            score = score +1;
            window.location="game3.php";
        }
```